# Launch4J with bundled 64 bit JVM, want it to download 32 bit JVM if needed

Tags: java, jvm, launch4j

I'm trying to generate a single executable for my app.

95% of the time it will be installed on a 64 bit OS, and management doesn't want it to ask the user to download and install a JRE.  So we bundle the 64 bit JRE.

The problem is that when the app IS installed on a 32 bit OS, Launch4J still tries to use the 64 bit JVM.  (we get the windows "app not compatible with this version of Windows" error.)

```
<bundledJre64bit>true</bundledJre64bit>
<runtimeBits>32/64</runtimeBits>
<jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
```

Shouldn't it be detecting a 32 bit OS, and ignoring the 64 bit bundled JRE?

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Will the 32-bit Jvm run on the 64-bit platform? If yes, you could bundle that.

Comment: That doesn't actually help.  We want the user to use a 64 bit JVM if possible, and 95% of our users are running on a 64 bit platform.

Comment: There is no need not to use a 32-bit Jvm unless you need more than 1-2gb ram. But ok, make two bundles then.

Comment: So, you are saying that it's impossible for Launch4J to detect it's running on a 32bit OS, and to NOT use the embedded 64 bit JVM?

Comment: No - i don't know. Launch4j is open source so just have a look yourself.